# Extract streams from WebM

Tags: video, file-formats, software-recommendation

I hope my question fits the theme of this SE.

Is there any software that can extract streams from WebM videos? I don't want to convert (re-compress), I want the streams intact. Thanks.

Comment: It's close to off-topic, but I think there are enough legitimate uses for this in a studio/production context (which is what the site is really about) for it to be on-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote: "Since WebM is a Matroska subset, mkvtoolnix should let you demux the files. It's open source, cross platform, and the author provides binaries for Windows."

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/412890/lossless-extraction-of-streams-from-webm